# Azure copyBlob Node.js API Error

Tags: node.js, azure

Does anyone successfully use copyBlob Node.js API to copy a blob from one container to the other? I tried to use copyBlob API in server scripts, but it always gives me error such as "Error: Container name format is incorrect."

My code structure is like this:

```
blobService.copyBlob(uri, containerName, blobName, function (error) {

    if (error != null) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        request.respond();
    }
});
```

My code is provided below:

```
10   var blobService = azure.createBlobService('mystorage', accountKey, 'mystorage.blob.core.windows.net');       
11    
12    blobService.copyBlob("http://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/e0f57621-20a3-4e17-b418-c0139c6daef8/myimage.jpg", "container1", "myimage.jpg", function (error) {
13        if (error != null) {
14           console.log(error);
15        } else { 
16           console.log("success");                                    
17        }                      
18    });
```

and the error message I always received is

```
Error in script '/table/myblob.insert.js'. Error: Container name format is incorrect.
[external code]
at insert (</table/myblob.insert.js>:12:17)
at </table/myblob.insert.js>:1:8
[external code]
```

I'm pretty sure the string format of containerName is correct.

Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the actual values sent in `uri`, `containerName` and `blobName` variables?

Comment: Sure, the actual values in uri, containerName, and blobName are "http://mystorage1.blob.core.windows.net/mystorage-container1/blob1.jpg", "mystorage-container2", and "blob1.jpg". Thanks!

Comment: This is really strange....I not only see the "Container name format is incorrect." error message but also see "Error: Container name must be a non empty string." sometimes. I am pretty sure that my containerName is a non-empty string...

Comment: I just tried it and it worked perfectly fine for me. Indeed weird! Please double check the container name. Look at the code here: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/lib/common/lib/util/validate.js (containerNameIsValid function) for all the validation rules SDK is using.

Comment: Would you mind to share any code segment that works for you? I think my container name should be valid; otherwise I wouldn't be able to create it using createContainerIfNotExists(). I am thinking I might miss something that I haven't realize in my code. so any working example will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just posting my sample code as answer. Do take a look and I will delete it afterwards.

```
var AZURE = require('azure');
var blobService = AZURE.createBlobService("cynapta", "accountkey");
blobService.copyBlob("https://cynapta.blob.core.windows.net/mystorage-container1/tsmile.png", "mystorage-container2", "tsmile.png", function (error) {
    if (error != null) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log("copied successfully.");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This just looks like what I have done in my code, but unfortunately, I still get the same errors.....sigh....

Comment: Can you post complete code in your question? I'm sure there's something trivial which is missing.

Comment: I took the liberty of updating your question with the code you posted as answer. I hope you don't mind. Anyways, I tried your code and still unable to reproduce the error. Is your target container name `container1` as you mentioned in your code? What version of node.js are you running? I'm running version `0.6.20` (`node --version`).

Comment: Yes, "container1" is my target container name. I'm not sure how to check the version of Node.js from Azure Portal, but I guess I'm using the default version which is 0.6.20.

Comment: I've been running the code from command prompt on my computer (Windows 8.1). Can you try doing the same? You mentioned that your code is running in Azure. Is it running in a website, mobile service or a node worker role?

Comment: The code is running in Azure Mobile Service. I'm currently testing the code through Windows Azure Portal and will try the suggested command prompt approach.

Comment: I have checked that the node.js version I'm using is 0.8.26 that is the default version mobile service currently supports. Mobile service doesn't seem to allow users to change the node.js version.

Comment: the `azure-storage` npm module uses `startCopyBlob`. `client.startCopyBlob('http://' + account + '.blob.core.windows.net/' + container, target, blob, callback)`

Answer (score 0):

I googled a bit and found this:

The container name must be a valid DNS name, conforming to the following naming rules:

1. Container names must start with a letter or number, and can contain only letters, numbers, and the dash (-) character.
2. Every dash (-) character must be immediately preceded and followed by a letter or number; consecutive dashes are not permitted in container names.
3. All letters in a container name must be lowercase.
4. Container names must be from 3 through 63 characters long.
5. Avoid blob names that end with a dot (.), a forward slash (/), or a sequence or combination of the two.